# why i cant use htaccess in xampp?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my name is mr.rico , i just build up my website for a anime call akifansubs.com.
my design and the program is not have any problem.... but....

where i try to use .htaccess file my xampp does'nt respons

ex 
`akifansubs/index.php` become like this `akifansubs/index`.

and this the code for htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
# Replace html with your file extension, eg: php, htm, asp
```

this is what i found a few hours ago

what should i do ? try to u make some change in xampp httpd con but it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that this question was asked multiple times already and is answered, but I will give a little more comprehensive answer based on my experience.

Here is the .htaccess code snippet that will help you:

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
```

I want to stress some important things here for everybody's reference:

This code snippet doesn't remove entry scripts from url (such as index.php used by many PHP frameworks)
It only removes .php extension, if you want to remove other extension as well (e.g. .html), copy and paste 3rd block and replace php with other extension.
Don't forget to also remove extension from anchors (links) href.

Comment: hmm .... , i will try it . but did you know how to active the xammp for read the .htaccess ?

Comment: Just had a similar issue


Resolved it by checking in `htttp.conf` 

         # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
         # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
         #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
         #
         AllowOverride All   <--- make sure this is not set to "None"

It is worth bearing in mind I tried (from Mark's answer) the "put garbage in the .htaccess" which did give a server error - but even though it was being read, it wasn't being acted on due to no overrides allowed.

Comment: they said the #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so is remove the # and it will be LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so. and i try change it but that doesnt effect at all , htaccess cant read by xampp. the page says object not found

Comment: Turn AllowOverride All -> AllowOverride None and restart apache. See if that works.

Comment: xampp already set the setting :( , why ..... my all my friends can do it but i cant , how pathetic  i am ....